# I can't use the command "python3" but can use "python" without "3", and I have installed python by the way

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use the command prompt to run a python file I can just use the command "python", but when I try to use "python3" the command prompt give me an error that says:
***Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings

> Manage App Execution Aliases.***
> I use python 3.9.7 in windows 10
> I want to know why when I add "3" to "python" the prompt gives me an error

Comment: Then I advise not to use the `3`.

Comment: isn't python3 aliased under `py3` in windows?

Comment: Have you installed python3? `python` often refers to python2. Try running `python --version`

Comment: @JamesGeddes no, the Windows distribution of Python 3 only has python.exe

Comment: @MattDMo the `python` command just points to python.exe

Comment: @JamesGeddes Yes. That's how Windows works. If I have an executable called `my_program.exe`, as long as it's either in the current directory or a directory on my `PATH`, I can just type `my_program` into CMD or Powershell or Git Bash or whatever, and the program will run. The `.exe` is implied.

Comment: Ah, you mean that "python3" is just a command for mac not windows right?